# Java Client API for Raven DB

Tags: java, nosql, ravendb

Anyone aware of Java Client API for Raven DB ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, RavenDb now has  [a Java API][1]

[1]: http://ayende.com/blog/164546/ravendb-webinar-mystery-feature-3-native-java-api-is-now-available-on-the-tubes - from the authors of Raven.

Comment: Also see http://ayende.com/blog/168354/what-is-new-in-ravendb-3-0-jvm-client-api — official Java client in 3.0

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no such. But you can certainly use the Http-API to utilize RavenDB from a Java application: http://ravendb.net/documentation/docs-http-api-index

Comment: And it should be fairly simple to port the client to java

Answer (score 0):

Client for 3.0 or 3.5: 
https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22net.ravendb%22%20AND%20a%3A%22ravendb-client%22

Client for 4.0:
https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22net.ravendb%22%20AND%20a%3A%22ravendb%22